# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2+n)(x-1)^n$ closed form

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need help to find the closed form of the following power series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2+n)(x-1)^n$$

Edit: I have added a solution in the answers below :)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn

Comment: if you dont show some work, some nice users will vote to close your post. try to add some work .

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Note that you have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2+n)(x-1)^n
 = (x-1)^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)(x-1)^{n-1}
$$
and the sum can be recognized as a second derivative of something very familiar...

Comment: @StrugglingStudent made a mistake, please see the corrected version.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=x-1$ and consider $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2+n)X^n$$
The trick being to write
$$n^2=n(n-1)+n$$ you then face
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1) X^n+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n X^n=X^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1) X^{n-2}+2X\sum_{n=1}^\infty n X^{n-1}$$ that is to say
$$S=X^2 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X^{n}\right)''+2X\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X^{n}\right)'$$

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers, I think I have gotten the correct solution and verified it with Mathematica.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2+n)(x-1)^n$ = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2-n+2n)(x-1)^n$ = $$(x-1)^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2-n)(x-1)^{n-2} + 2(x-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n)(x-1)^{n-1}$$

And using the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ about $x_0 = 1$ and its first and second derivatives, you get $$f(x) = (x-1)^2*\frac{2}{(2-x)^2} + \frac{2(x-1)}{(2-x)^2} = \frac{2x-2}{(2-x)^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Start with

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n=\frac{z}{1-z},\quad |z|<1$$

differentiate both sides

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$$

now multiply both sides by $z^2$ then differentiate

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2+n)z^n=\frac{2z}{(1-z)^3}$$

set $z=x-1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2+n)(x-1)^n=\frac{2(x-1)}{(2-x)^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(1-z)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{infty}  z^k ,~ |z|<1~~~(1)$$
Differentiaate w.r.t.xz, we get
$$\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}= \sum k z^{k}~~~~(2)$$ 
Multiply (2) by $z^2$ and differentiate w. r. t. $z$, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k(k+1) z^k =\frac{2z}{(1-z)^3}~~~~(3)$$
Now, by putting $z=(x-1)$ in (3), we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k(k+1)(x-1)^k= \frac{2(x-1)}{(2-x)^3},~~ 0<x <2.$$